# Enable Apply Edits With Global Ids on ArcGIS Feature Services

Tags: arcgis-server, feature-service

I have published a Feature Service on our ArcGIS Server 10.4.1 and in support section of the Feature Service URL I am seeing that the

> ApplyEdits With Global Ids: false

[image]

can you please let me know why this is false? and how can I update it to True?

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, if you check the box to enable sync capabilities on the feature service during publishing, it should set it to true provided that you have the GlobalID field on your table. It also requires the database to technically be a geodatabase.